# When is 'mapping.getInputForward()' used?

Tags: struts, struts-1

I would like to know what `mapping.getInputForward()` does in Struts. The API says that it creates and returns an `ActionForward` that corresponds to the input of the Action.

But I don't understand what this means. Could anybody explain to me more clearly? Can I use this method to return to the previous page? And if I can, how do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getInputForward()` does precisely what it says it does: it returns an `ActionForward` corresponding to the action's `input` attribute value.

You probably wouldn't want to use it as a general "return to previous page", because that wouldn't make any sense. It's commonly used when calling validation "by hand" and there's a validation error; the `input` value would be the form page. In those cases it's similar to "return to previous page", but different, because it's generally a forward (not a redirect) to the form JSP.

That said, it's just a normal `findForward` but for the action's `input` page.